# How can I use axios for fetching data in gatsby useStaticQuery?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, graphql, gatsby

I can use graphql for fetching data in gatsby like this :

```
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"

const IndexPage = () => {

  const gatsbyRepoData = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      github {
        repository(name: "gatsby", owner: "gatsbyjs") {
          id
          nameWithOwner
          url
        }
      }
    }
  `)
```

How can I use axios to fetch a rest api with useStaticQuery lifecycle in gatsby js ?

Comment: `useStaticQuery` is a internal gatsby hook for querying internal 'server' ONLY ... REST apis can be queried using 'source plugins' ... dynamic fetching is a separate story, described in docs, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. The purpose of `useStaticQuery` is to get static data (hence the name) from your project, your metadata, or, depending on your data structure, your own project files.

To get dynamic data from outer sources you need to use a `gatsby-node.js` file.

Check:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/use-static-query/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/2019-02-20-introducing-use-static-query/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/data-fetching/

Answer (score 1):

If you want functionality from a REST API similar to the `useStaticQuery` function in Gatsby, you can try the [gatsby-source-rest-api](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-rest-api/). This will allow you to write graphql for querying the REST API.

The repo https://github.com/mustapha-benmbarek/gatsby-source-rest-api has an example of its usage.

The example's `gatsby-config.js` contains:

```
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: "gatsby-source-rest-api",
    options: {
      endpoints: ["https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"]
    }
  }
]
```

And then the example uses this `useStaticQuery` on a page to pull data from that endpoint, selecting only certain fields to read from it:

```
const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
  query {
    allRestApiUsers {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          phone
          email
          address {
            city
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`);
```

The endpoint it is reading from contains a json structure like the following, you can see how it is using the graphql query to parse it:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  ...
]
```